# Maximum number of partition function objects

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

What is the maximum number of partition scheme objects, and partition function objects? (SQL Server 2019)

Note, this is not the partition number per table (which is 15 000), but just how much such schema objects can be created?

I'll have a database where each client has a schema, and need to create a dedicated partition scheme and function for each, but cannot find that limit on BOL.

Comment: Considering that the data type for the `id` of a partition function is an `int` (relevant [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-partition-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)) then you would be limited to the maximum value of an `int`.

Comment: Just note that things slow way down when you get to high thresholds of just about _any_ type of entity. The more objects/partitions you create, the more likely you'll run into things like [this](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/sql-performance/sys-partitions) and [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6309/use-caution-with-sysdmdbdatabasepageallocations-in-sql-server/) - sometimes it will be code you can control, but sometimes it won't. Also keep [this in mind](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7287/sql-server-table-partitioning-maximum-15000-partitions/).

Comment: There is no defined limit for partition schemes from what I recall.  You may hit some other tensile limit in the engine before it matters, but they are just entries in a metadata table or two under the covers.  You're asking "how many rows can I store in a table" more or less

Comment: Maybe i'm missing something but *why* would you need different partition functions/schema for each customer? I understand they have own tables. But I don't see that the storage functions are schemabound. Does each customer have such unique requirements of how the data should be arranged?

Comment: @siggemannen yes, clients have different retention period in their data, hence one client's partitions might be still full for but for other they are already purged

Comment: So you have fixed number of years or whatever as retention period, but different customers join your company at different times so they need own partitions. or bigger clients just have longer retention times. maybe i'm a simple guy, but to me it sounds a bit overcomplicated :) Surely you can have logic that handles purging /switching out from some common setting table instead of handling it in every partition scheme.

Answer (score 1):

> I'll have a database where each client has a schema,

There's your problem.  In SQL Server a database is a pretty lightweight container; give each client a database your life will be much easier.

Comment: thanks, but this db will be moved to Azure managed instance in the future, where the db limit is 100 ... i have already hundreds of schemas for different customers

Comment: 100 per MI, but you'll want to have a few separate MIs.   You'll eventually run out of storage or compute resources otherwise.  And each MI can be as small as 4 vCores.  It _is_ the case in MI that databases can't share files.  So there may be some benefit in maintaining your multi-schema approach, at least for smaller clients.  But you should definitely not plan on having every client in the same database and only having one MI.

Comment: Using separate databases (and separate MIs) will also prevent you from hitting _other_ kinds of limits, e.g. if you put 10,000 schemas in a single database and ever accidentally expand the schemas node in SSMS... it's worse for tables and users because they also load a bunch of additional things (columns, triggers, indexes, effective permissions, etc. etc). Basically a single container for thousands of customers is going to fall over in all kinds of ways. From almost exactly a decade ago: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33556/1186

Comment: You should make sure you build into the schema and application logic *now* the thing you will *eventually* need: the ability for two customers to live in two different databases or in two different MIs. Schema name is just an abstraction layer / container like the other two, but I can tell you from experience, digging yourself out of the single database hole later will be problematic.